# Unbalanced square brackets in spawning a custom villager

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Just a heads up, if I seem inexperienced in typing my question in a certain style, please forgive me!

I used a command generator, from [this link](https://minecraftcommand.science/shop-generator), to spawn a villager who sells custom weapons.

However, the generator does not support villagers selling custom WEAPONS, only custom ITEMS. That means I have to enter the values myself, given the format provided. I have 2 more of such commands and they work perfectly fine, but only this one has a persistent problem.

The command is extremely long (well, at least for me) and correcting the unbalanced brackets is an uphill task for my inexperienced self. I hope any experts on Minecraft data tagging could help me out; I would be really grateful. Here's the full error I got, I decided to remove the format because I got it all wrong:

```
[21:46:35] Data tag parsing failed:Unbalanced square brackets []:
{Profession:0,CustomName:"The Shop Elf #3",CustomNameVisible:1,Career:1,CareerLevel:42,CanPickUpLoot:0,PersistenceRequired:1,Invulnerable:1,Attributes:[{Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Base:"1f"},{Name:"generic.movementSpeed",Base:"0f"},{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:99999}],Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:"nether_star",Count:5},buyB:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"golden_hoe",Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"The Lucky Golden Scythe",Lore:["Is that really gold... or just children's glitter?","You get more resources by slaying mobs."]},ench:[{id:16,lvl:3},{id:21,lvl:3},{id:34,lvl:2},{id:35,lvl:5}]},MaxUses:9999999},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"nether_star",Count:7},buyB:{id:"dye",Count:1,Damage:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"golden_hoe",Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"Mace of Tarrasque",Lore:["Preserves the blood of an extinct monster.","Boosts your health dramatically."]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:50,Operation:0,UUIDMost:30803,UUIDLeast:806745},{AttributeName:"generic.knockbackResistance",Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Amount:1,Operation:1,UUIDMost:34336,UUIDLeast:736873}],ench:[{id:16,lvl:1},{id:19,lvl:3},{id:21,lvl:1},{id:34,lvl:5},{id:35,lvl:1}]},MaxUses:9999999},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"nether_star",Count:8},buyB:{id:"diamond",Count:3 maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"diamond_axe",Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"Sapphire Daedalus",Lore:["The second most powerful weapon of the land.","Extremely high damage and health."]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:35,Operation:0,UUIDMost:90871,UUIDLeast:499725},{AttributeName:"generic.knockbackResistance",Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Amount:0,Operation:0,UUIDMost:66479,UUIDLeast:426152}],ench:[{id:16,lvl:5},{id:17,lvl:5},{id:18,lvl:5},{id:19,lvl:5},{id:20,lvl:5},{id:21,lvl:1},{id:34,lvl:1},{id:35,lvl:1}]},MaxUses:9999999},rewardExp:false}]}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a `}` near the end.  You're closing off the `Recipes` list prior to closing out the final item compound tag.  After the last `rewardExp:false` tag, your closing brackets should look like `}}]}}` instead of what you currently have, which is `}]}}`.

Comment: You mean `Recipes`, not `Recipies` :P

Comment: @CommandFox: oops

Comment: Thank you very much for solving the problem!

Also, how do you minimise the command into that little box? It would very much help me later on! :-)

Comment: Are you referring to how I formatted the command?  I used a code block (also known as preformatted text).  Take a look at the [formatting help](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for more information.